# PHP DOMDocument with åäö (UTF-8)

Tags: php, utf-8, domdocument

I got a HTML/PHP5 page with a form, then when it gets posted, it creates a XML file with the form input as data.

But all **åäö** looks like if I had used `utf8_encode()` on them. I can't `utf8_decode()` them, because then the "service" I send the XML files to, complains that is not UTF-8 (like it should).

**Parser failed. Reason :2: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE5 0x73 0x61 0x2E**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Blabla></title>
    </head>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<name>Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶</name>
```

I have tried m`b_convert_encoding()`, sending the data as `CDATA` with `htmlentities()` instead and changed `default_charset = "utf-8"` in php.ini but nothing works like it supposed to.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were nothing wrong with the DOMDocument, I just forgot to specify UTF-8 in htmlentities() when I outputted the result.

Comment: If your data is UTF-8, why don’t you use UTF-8 for your output too?

Comment: I did, but I missed that the standard charset for the htmlentities() method is ISO-8859-1, then when I used htmlentities() on my UTF-8 data it transformed my åäö to Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶.

The reason I use htmlentities() on the data is to show it on a webpage with <>.